# Outline for setting up triple integrals

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I just need some general outline of how to set those up, or what to look for. For example, in have the following:

Find the volume of the region bounded above by the plane

$$ z=2-x-y $$

and below by the square

$$ R: 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0 \leq y \leq 1$$

What are the steps needed to properly set up the an integral of form

$$V=\iiint_a \ \,dz\,dy\,dx$$

And how does one decide the order in which to integrate it?

Here's how I would approach such a problem. Since the limits of integration were basically laid out, it follows that  $ 0 \leq z \leq 2$. So would the integral look somewhat like this ?

$$\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{2-x-y} 1 \,dz\,dy\,dx$$

It seems too easy and trivial to me, which is why I think I'm misunderstanding this completely.

Comment: I can barely do a single integral what..

Comment: @SakethMalyala Doing them is not nearly as hard as it looks. You're basically just doing a single integral three times.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your limits of integration for $x$ and $y$ are correct, but your limits of integration for $z$ should be $0 \le z \le 2 - x - y$.

Another thing is that you have your integrals in the wrong order. The $\int_0^2$ should be the rightmost integral if you're integrating with respect to $z$ first (i.e. if you have $dz$ first).

Answer (score 1):

When integrating up to a function of $z$, in your case $z=2-x-y$, the upper limit of integration for $z$ should be that function. Also, the limits of integration are in the wrong order. The innermost integral is evaluated first, so the limits for $z$ should be on the inside.

Comment: Oh right my bad, I'll edit that.